# Trying to calculate the average of inputs given using do-while and while loop but it keeps stopping

Tags: java, while-loop, average, do-while

The main gist of the script is to keep asking for grades until the user inputs a negative number. Once a negative number has been input, it calculates the average of those grades. The grade that was input by the user can only be 4-10.

I've been for hours now trying to figure this out.. If I enter only invalid inputs or only valid inputs it works fine, but the second I try to mix it up the script stops.

For example: If I enter 4(valid input) the script asks for another grade. If I enter 3(invalid input) the script says that the input was invalid and asks for another valid input. After that if I enter 4 again it just stops working, when its supposed to just keep going like this until I enter a negative number to make it start calculating the average of valid inputs.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Average {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("The program will calculate the average of the user inputted grades.");
System.out.println("The program will start calculating with any negative integer");

double grade;   
double sum = 0;
int count = 0;



do {
    System.out.print("Input grade (4-10): ");
    grade = scanner.nextDouble();

    if (grade >= 4 && grade <= 10){
        sum = sum + grade;
        count++; 
    }



} while (grade >= 4 && grade <= 10);

 {


while (grade >= 0 && grade < 4 || grade > 10){

    System.out.println("Invalid grade!");
    System.out.print("Input grade (4-10): ");
    grade = scanner.nextDouble();


    if (grade < 0){

        System.out.println(count + " grades were given.");
        System.out.println("Average: " + sum/count);
        break;
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: `but the second I try to mix it up the script stops` Mix what up? What do you mean by 'stops'?

Comment: Well, it stops because the second condition `while (grade >= 0 && grade < 4 || grade > 10){` is not true (`grade` is still that negative number and therefore this condition returns `false`).

Comment: @copeg I edited into the original post an example of what I mean by mixing it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because your loops are separated, so if first is false, second works only once and then stops. Try something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Average {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("The program will calculate the average of the user inputted grades.");
        System.out.println("The program will start calculating with any negative integer");

        double sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        double grade;

        do{
            System.out.print("Input grade (4-10): ");
            grade = scanner.nextDouble();

            if(grade >= 4 && grade <= 10){
                    sum = sum + grade;
                    count++;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Invalid grade!");
            }
        }while(grade >= 0);

        System.out.println(count + " grades were given.");
        System.out.println("Average: " + sum/count);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the first while loop is for valid input only and the second loop for invalid input only, in other words if you in put 3 and 5, it is already out of both loops.

try this

```
while(true) {
    System.out.print("Input grade (4-10): ");
    grade = scanner.nextDouble();
    if(grade < 0){
        System.out.println(count + " grades were given.");
        System.out.println("Average: " + sum / count);
        break;
    }
    if(grade >= 4 && grade <= 10){
        sum = sum + grade;
        count++;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid grade!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had not idea it was this simple, my mind is blown right now!

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid embedded whiles/do-whiles - as you are experiencing they are difficult to read and so it can be hard to figure out what's going on. What you are trying to achieve can be achieved much more easily using a single while loop:

```
System.out.print("Input grade (4-10): ");
grade = scanner.nextDouble();

while (grade >= 0)
{
    if (grade < 4 || grade > 10)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid grade!");
    }
    else
    {
        sum = sum + grade;
        count++;
    }

    System.out.print("Input grade (4-10): ");
    grade = scanner.nextDouble();
}
```